# Select only Checkbox input in getElementsByTagName, exclude the Textbox input

Tags: javascript, checkbox, textbox

I have one problem. The systems works fine when I select the checkboxes, the Total value changes, but as soon as I modify the text input, it changes to 0. I need to exclude this textbox input from changing the value.

here is the html:

```
       <input type="checkbox" id="15000"/>$15000<br/>
       <input type="checkbox" id="9400"/>$9400<br/>
       <label>Quantity</label><input class="text" type="text" maxlength="3" size="2" value="1" name="qty"></input>

       <div id="total">$5000</div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
  var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var total = document.getElementById("total");

  var prev;

  for(i=0;i<input.length;i++){
  input[i].onchange = function(){
    if(this.checked){
    $("#total").fadeOut(300);
    $("#total").fadeIn(300);
    prev=parseFloat(total.innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9\,]+/g,"")) + parseFloat(this.id);
         total.innerHTML = "$ " + prev.formatMoney(0, ',', '.');
    }else{
     $("#total").fadeOut(300);
     $("#total").fadeIn(300);
     prev=parseFloat(total.innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9\,]+/g,"")) - parseFloat(this.id);
         total.innerHTML = "$ " + prev.formatMoney(0, ',', '.');
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M7My9/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `if(this.type=='text')` in the first line of onchange handler to detect the type of the input

Comment: I added if(this.type!='text') on top of onchange, thanks a lot buddy! :)

Answer (score 6):

Try below

```
if(document.getElementsByTagName("input").type == "checkbox")
```

Please check updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/M7My9/26/)

Comment: Where can I add this line?

Comment: I tried to assign something like this, but it's not working: var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input").type("checkbox");
@AshReva

Comment: After you initialise var input variable use this if (input).type == "checkbox").  Use this before your for loop start

Comment: Unfortunately i am answering from my iphone so fiddle doesnt open on iphone. Will give u response for sure

Comment: it's ok, I will use @jonasnas one, works like charm. Dunno why yours didn't work. but thanks :D

Comment: @HerlandCid can you show me your updated fiddle which is working

Comment: @HerlandCid I have updated answer with link to working fiddle. Please accept answer if its ok with you.

Comment: That will tell if an element IS a checkbox.  But it will not select anything.  It will not help you selectElementsByTagName().